# python loop a list

Tags: python, list

my text file has about 100 rows and I want to iterate through them and add quotes to the first value. It however, only iterates through row 1 and does not go through the rest of my 100 rows. Can someone help me?

```
 line2List = []

    while True:
      line2 = compFile.readline()
      if line 2 == "":
         break
      line2List.append(line2)
      s = line2List[0]
      s = '""' + s
```

Comment: Please post all of your code.

Comment: The posted code has syntax errors (as Blender stated) and does not match with the description.  What should `s = '""' + s` do (at this position)?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
line2List = []

while True:
  line2 = compFile.readline()
  if line2 == "": # REMOVED SPACE
     break
  line2List.append('""' + line2)
```

Comment: @pythonNoob123 if the answer is what you are looking for you should accept it, it gives you increased reputation, it gives the person who took the time to reply increased reputation, and it helps future people find the best answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like it will do anything good:

```
if line 2 == "":
```

Do you mean:

```
if line2 == "":
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you really want - maybe something like this acceptable too:

```
lines = open(filename).readlines()

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for x in (y for y in lines if y.strip()):       
        f.write('""' + x + '\n')
```